# Redirect view after login with facebook using Firebase and Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, ionic-framework, firebase

Authentication is functioning normally, but once I login, it continues in the same view.

I need after login he goes to the view `dash.html`

As I redirect the user after he login?

```
$scope.loginFacebook = function(){

  var ref = new Firebase("https://<NAME>.firebaseio.com");
  var authObject = $firebaseAuth(ref);

  authObject.$authWithOAuthRedirect("facebook").then(function(authData) {
    console.log(authData);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('error' + error);
  })
}
```

Comment: tried `$location.path('myRoute')`?

Comment: Thanks! but I used `$state.go('myRoute');`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I used `$state.go('tabs.home');` but I had to put it in the app.factory rather than in the controller.

```
auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
    $state.go('tabs.home');
    if(authData) {
        angular.copy(authData, Auth.user);
        Auth.user.profile = $firebaseObject(....));
    } else {
        if(Auth.user && Auth.user.profile) {
        }
        angular.copy({}, Auth.user);
    }
});
```